# Python 3.x : I'm out of range

Tags: python-3.x, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm asking to have some help cause I believe I know why I'm out of range but I don't know out to solved it. Thanks you :D

```
#Import input.
from pathlib import Path
test = Path(r'C:\Users\Helphy\Desktop\Perso\GitHub\Advent_of_Code_2021\Day_3\Input.txt').read_text().split("\n")
#Defined some variable 
temp = []
finalnumtemp = []
finalnum = []
f_num = []
zero = 0
one = 0
for t in range(len(test)):
    for j in range(len(test)):
        temp = list(test[j])
        print(temp)
        finalnumtemp.append(temp[j])
        print(finalnumtemp)
     """for i in range(len(finalnumtemp)):
        if int(finalnumtemp[i]) == 0:
            zero += 1
        else:
            one += 1
    if zero > one:
        finalnum.append(0)
    else:
        finalnum.append(1)
    zero == 0
    one == 0
    finalnumtemp = []
print(finalnum)"""
```

```
    Input :
    00100
    11110
    10110
    10111
    10101
    01111
    00111
    11100
    10000
    11001
    00010
    01010
```

```
error: An exception has occurred: IndexError 
list index out of range
  File "C: \ Users \ Helphy \ Desktop \ Perso \ GitHub \ Advent_of_Code_2021 \ Day_3 \ Day_3.py", line 16, in <module>
    finalnumtemp.append (temp [j])
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: that done tell if it's good

Comment: Ask yourself questions what data type is `test` variable? What do I receive in `temp = list(test[j])`? What is the length of `temp` list and if `j` is in `range(len(test))` is this really related to `temp` value length? Can I do `temp[j]` here or it's different length? Try to use better names for variables, would be easier to separate them visually.

Comment: Ok i done that ^^ that true my variable names are not really fine to analyze. But in fact i under stand the probleme and where is it but i don't know you to solved it ^^' 
thanks again to your help

Comment: `test` variable receives a `List[str]` type, then `temp` receives `list of chars` cause when you do `test[j]` you refer to a `str` and when you do `list(test[j])` you convert string to list of chars. Your `j in range(len(test))`, let's say len(test) can be 100 words in your test file. When `len(temp)` is length of single word, let's say 5 characters, so `temp[j]` is wrong, cause `j` goes more than max index. You need to change this line use `t` index instead: `for j in range(len(test[t])):`

Comment: Thanks you i solved it. really and i promise to have bettre name ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What to solve? What did you intend for the program to achieve?

You have an error because...

- `j` goes from `0` to `len(test)`, that is, `12`
- `test[j]` as `temp` has only 5 elements.

To select among the digits in `temp`, the index should be something of `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` (first, second, third, ... from the left) or `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, `-4`, `-5` (first, second, third, ... from the right).

To append the first of `temp` to `finalnumtemp`, fix

```
        finalnumtemp.append(temp[j])
```

to

```
        finalnumtemp.append(temp[0])
```

Comment: There is the notice of the exercice : https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/3
I would like to take the first num of temp for each loop.
Excuse me for my english ^^'
I'll make an exemple
00100
    11110
    10110
    10111
    10101
    01111
    00111
    11100
    10000
    11001
    00010
    01010
I'll take the first column there is more 1 than 0 so the result is 1
and i restart 
2nd column there is more 0 than 1 so i add it to the last result like : 10
and again to finish at 10110.

Comment: Yes, but i need to change with the loop the column of temp like  :
```
finalnumtemp.append(temp[0])
    Loop to check the sum
finalnumtemp.append(temp[1])
    Etc and etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look into list comprehension. I know it is maybe a bit daunting at first but I personally found it to make much more sense than nested for loops after I had gotten the hang of them. You could convert your strings of zeros and ones into lists of separate integers in a single line:

```
numbers = [[int(char) for char in line] for line in test]
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0], ... , [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

And then fetch the first number (or any number really):

```
first_num = [num[0] for num in numbers]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

And even perform operations on the lists if you wish:

```
sum_num = [sum(num) for num in numbers]
[1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2]
```

Nested for loops can get real messy real quick. I know this isn't the actual answer to the question, but I thought it might be helpful regardless.